# Strangest thing for the footer of this microsite

Tags: css, html, layout, footer

Check this on firebug, the div with an idea of footer specifically :
http://club-avantages.alarmefast.com/

Now, check the very same thing on this page :
http://club-avantages.alarmefast.com/contact.php

and also the page commande.php

I realize the code for this site is kind of messy, but it was done hastefully, and now on those last two pages I am left with a footer that for some reason gets stuck at the top of the screen, but whose content sticks to the bottom...

Any help you may provide ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Eh i don't see it. I'm using FF, but it looks ok to me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me, on the contact page the footer doesn't show the padding but on the home it does. The reason it does this is, you have elements floated in there and the parent div(#footer) doesn't surround the elements. Simple fix is add float:left or overflow:hidden and it will fix it.